# Check for the string with decimal place seperated by comma - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to check this format;

> 1.234.567,89

Only one comma is permitted for the Entry.

Current code

```
Regex.Match(((TextChangedEventArgs)e).NewTextValue, @"^[0-9]+(\,[0-9]+)?$");
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what you have tried

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel kindly look above

Comment: Source for the data? Is it user input, if so you can mask the textbox or write your own textbox to handle the input as they enter it. If it's not coming from the user, do you just want to verify it? Do you want regex to do this?

Comment: @Stuart I need to verify via Text Watcher

Comment: Is the comma required?

Answer (score 6):

You should not use regex to check if a string can be parsed to a `decimal`/`double`. Use [`decimal.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx) (or `double.TryParse`):

```
string moneyText = "1.234.567,89";
var myCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
decimal money;
bool validFormat = decimal.TryParse(moneyText, NumberStyles.Currency, myCulture, out money);
if (validFormat)
    Console.WriteLine("Valid format, parsed value was " + money.ToString("C"));
```

Comment: I was looking for the same answer but didn´t got it completely :) Yours is far better than mine.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I need to be sure to be written only one comma to Entry field. Your solution is just the half. What if there is two comma and valid format is false, how to delete unnecessary comma programatically?

Comment: @erdemgc: so you have formats like `1.234,567,89` and the fixed result is `1.234.567,89`? If the user enters invalid formats, why do you try to fix it and don't ask the user to enter a correct value? What if user uses english culture and enters `1,234,567`, that's perfectly valid

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to enforce possibilities by using non capturing lookaheads (`?=` `?!`) which we can enforce all rules *before a match*.

Rules are

- Only numbers, a comma or periods, a general rule.
- Only allow one comma
- Enforce a comma
- Don't allow two consecutive periods.

These patterns are commented so use the option `IgnorePatternWhitespace` or remove comments and join on one line.

**Comma Required**

```
^
(?=[\d\.,]+\Z) # Only allow decimals a period or a comma. 
(?=.*,)        # Enforce that there is a comma ahead.
(?!.*\.\.)     # Fail match if two periods are consecutive.
.+             # All rules satisfied, begin matching
$
```

**Comma and following value optional**

```
^
(?=[\d\.,]+\Z) # Only allow decimals a period or a comma. 
(?!.*\.\.)     # Fail match if two periods are consecutive.
[\d.]+         # All rules satisfied, begin matching
(,\d+)?        # If comma found, allow it but then only have decimals       
$              # This ensures there are no more commas and match will fail.
```